# How Do I Customize Spring Error Timestamps Without Causing Exceptions?

Tags: spring-boot

When there are errors in my backend, SpringBoot returns a json result with the errors.
I wanted to change the timestamp in the json to be readable so I customised the attributes:

```
@Component
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

  private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
  private static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(WebRequest webRequest, boolean includeStackTrace) {

    //Let Spring handle the error first
    Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, includeStackTrace);

    //Format & update timestamp
    Object timestamp = errorAttributes.get(TIMESTAMP);
    if(timestamp == null) {
      errorAttributes.put(TIMESTAMP, dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    } else {
      errorAttributes.put(TIMESTAMP, dateFormat.format((Date)timestamp));
    }

    return errorAttributes;
  }
}
```

However, now when there is a 404, an Exception is thrown because of this customisation:

> E 23:21:36 88 [dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:224) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]

The ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration is trying to parse the timestamp attribute:

```
    @Override
    public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            String message = getMessage(model);
            logger.error(message);
            return;
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Date timestamp = (Date) model.get("timestamp");
```

How can I customize the timestamp in the error response without affecting other standard error processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're working with an outdated version of spring mvc.
And we're talking about [ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java)
There was a bug:
[See here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/23256)

It was fixed in a commit `d1d953819ac9f0c0ece5160b96899030cabda46c` on Sep 12, 2020 into spring boot repository by Phil Webb into version 2.2.x and it's also been forward merged to 2.3.x and 2.4.x.

So now it looks like:

```
    private static class StaticView implements View {

        private static final MediaType TEXT_HTML_UTF8 = new MediaType("text", "html", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(StaticView.class);

        @Override
        public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws Exception {
            if (response.isCommitted()) {
                String message = getMessage(model);
                logger.error(message);
                return;
            }
            response.setContentType(TEXT_HTML_UTF8.toString());
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            // !!!note this line!!!!
            Object timestamp = model.get("timestamp");
            Object message = model.get("message");
            Object trace = model.get("trace");
            if (response.getContentType() == null) {
                response.setContentType(getContentType());
            }
            builder.append("<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1>").append(
                    "<p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p>")
                     // !!! and this line !!!
                    .append("<div id='created'>").append(timestamp).append("</div>")
                    .append("<div>There was an unexpected error (type=").append(htmlEscape(model.get("error")))
                    .append(", status=").append(htmlEscape(model.get("status"))).append(").</div>");
            if (message != null) {
                builder.append("<div>").append(htmlEscape(message)).append("</div>");
            }
            if (trace != null) {
                builder.append("<div style='white-space:pre-wrap;'>").append(htmlEscape(trace)).append("</div>");
            }
            builder.append("</body></html>");
            response.getWriter().append(builder.toString());
```

Having said that, usually people customize the error page (from my experience at least) and do not even use this default view.

There are plenty of tutorials about that, here is [one of them](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page)